How to simulate low-rank hamiltonian?
I want to implement a unitary $U\,,$
$$U=\text{exp}(-it|u\rangle\langle u|)\,,$$ where  $|u\rangle$ is a known state.
Are there any methods to do this efficiently?

What do you know about $|u\rangle$? For example, do you know that there exists a unitary $V$ that you can construct such that $|u\rangle=V|0\rangle$.

yeah all information of |u> is known, suppose there exists a unitary V one can construct such that |u⟩=V|0⟩

Let's assume that we know the circuit $V$ the constructs $|u\rangle$, i.e.
$$
V|0\rangle=|u\rangle.
$$
So, this reduces our problem to creating the evolution
$$
V^\dagger UV=e^{-it|0\rangle\langle 0|}.
$$
This is quite straightforward. For our computational register, we can ask "is it in the state $|0\rangle$?" essentially by applying $X$ on every qubit, and doing a multi-controlled-not targeting an ancilla initially in $|0\rangle$. Next, you simply apply a phase gate $|0\rangle\langle 0|+e^{-it}|1\rangle\langle 1|$ on the ancilla, before undoing the entanglement between ancilla and computational register by repeating the multi-controlled-not.


Thank you very much! Your method is quite useful.
